# Help with finding a specific passage in the Talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-kesubos

I'm currently involved in a research project about literacy in the Ancient Mediterranean, and I keep finding mentions of a passage in the Talmud referred to as [Ketubot 8:11 32c]. I checked Sefaria and other online Talmuds, but I can't find any that contain a passage with that numbering in Ketubot. Have I missed something fundamental about how the Talmud is ordered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took a bit of detective work but I think it refers to the 8<sup>th</sup> chapter of Massekhet Ketubot in the Jerusalem Talmud, halacha (law) 11, see the original [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14140&st=&pgnum=316).

If I [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Ketubot%208%3A11%2032c&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:%7Breferrer:source%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=MZwQWtrBOo6GtgeHoZi4Aw) `Ketubot 8:11 32c` the way you have it, I find multiple references (e.g., bottom of [here](https://www.biu.ac.il/JS/JSIJ/heb/sum2.html)) to the verse from [Deuteronomy 32:47](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.32.47?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which is the one referred in the gemara above (the reference 32 appears in the margin of the gemara).

See the Sefaria version of the gemara [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Ketubot.51a.1?lang=bi).

Puzzle solved I think.

*(I am less clear how the gemara relates to the content of the article from where you took the reference. Not even sure this is the correct reference. [Baba Batra 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.21a.2?lang=bi&with=Talmud&lang2=bi) seems much more interesting re literacy in the Ancient Mediterranean. You will tell us I guess.)*

Comment: Thanks! The part that I need seems to be in 50b, but that put me close enough to find it. One thing I still can't understand is why it would consistently be marked as 32c, even though every Talmudic numbering system I've seen only includes a and b. 
Bava Batra 21a is indeed of interest (especially the parts about class sizes, attitudes towards teachers, etc.), but I want to find sources from across multiple tractates, so I still have some digging to do.

Comment: The Venice edition of the Yerushalmi came with 4 columns per page. That's what 32c references: page 32 column 3. The Vilna edition used a different pagenation so people nowadays usually stick to Chapter and Halakha like 8:11, but this source was being extra clear I guess. Here's the original back side of page 32 in the Venice edition https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Yerushalmi-Venice-1523-HB45298.pdf&page=359 You'd want the right hand column, which is the third on the page (two on front, two on back).